# Connecting to a WCF service in php via NetTcpBinding

Tags: .net, php, wcf, nettcpbinding

I can't find a duplicate for this question, but I honestly hope I'm not the first to ask.

I have a WCF service that is sitting inside my LAN. For .NET clients on my lan, NetTcpBinding is the appropriate binding. However, one of my clients is a PHP web application. Is there any way to do this?

**Update:** I am well aware I can have multiple endpoints. I want to know if I can enjoy the speed, reduced network traffic and lack of latency of nettcp compared to wshttp from a php app.

It happens to be a PHP app running on windows so COM interop or .NET Interop would work. I'm wondering if there is a "native" solution, such a a pecl module or pear library.

Comment: +1 Have you been able to come up with a proper solution to use NetTcpBinding in PHP? I'm looking for same here.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I've not done it, but I posted a new answer speculating some possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NetTcpBinding is intended "for WCF-to-WCF communication" only**. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx))

This binding uses a proprietary protocol to communicate, and it is not meant to be interoperable since it is optimized for WCF-to-WCF.

You could have different endpoints for your WCF service. Why don't you expose another endpoint with a binding that could be consumed easily from your php application? (like BasicHttpBinding or WebHttpBinding)

Comment: Meant to and able too are two different things. But I will review that document.

Comment: @Justin: You could have different endpoints for your WCF service. Why don't you expose another endpoint with a binding that could be consumed easily from your php application?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another binding to an existing service endpoint. So why don't you just add a basichttp or wshttp binding in addition to the nettcpbinding. It is just a few lines in your config file and doesn't require any code change.

Comment: I want the compactness, speed, and lack of latency that netTcp gives over http.

Your suggestion is exactly what I do now.

Answer (score 0):

The following options are possible hacks. I include them there for others that find this question.

- [This](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/) allows you to make a .NET assembly with unmanaged exports you could call from a custom PHP module,
- [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) interprets PHP into the .NET runtime. It also gives you full access to the .NET API. I've only toyed a little with this. However, it definitely reads you web.config file. If it does not respect the WCF services aspect of the web.config, I would use [this PowerShell script](http://www.justaprogrammer.net/2012/02/11/using-powershell-to-call-a-wcf-service/), originally developed by [Christian Glessner](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/), as a reference for configuring a WCF service client stub completely in code.